# How to apply $urlRouterProvider.rule in all modules of my app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to make the trailing slash optional. I found a nice solution [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes), but my angularjs app has many modules, and I could only make it work copying and pasting the code in every module.

So, my question is: is it possible to apply this `$urlRouteProvider.rule` globally, to all my modules?

This is part of my app.js file:

```
angular.module('datasid', [ 'ngResource', 'ui.router',
                            'datasid.attendance.search',                                                   
                            'datasid.maps', ...]).

  config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state('home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            section: 'home'
    });

    // Allow trailing slash optional for all routes
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        var path = $location.url();

        // check to see if the path has a trailing slash
        if ('/' === path[path.length - 1]) {
            return path.replace(/\/$/, '');
        }

        if (path.indexOf('/?') > 0) {
            return path.replace('/?', '?');
        }

        return path;
    });

}).
```

And this is part of my maps.js file, which contains the datasid.maps module:

```
angular.module('datasid.maps', []).
  config(function($stateProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // Allow trailing slash optional for all routes
    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
        var path = $location.url();

        // check to see if the path has a trailing slash
        if ('/' === path[path.length - 1]) {
            return path.replace(/\/$/, '');
        }

        if (path.indexOf('/?') > 0) {
            return path.replace('/?', '?');
        }

        return path;
    });


    $stateProvider.
        state('maps', {
            url: '/maps',
            templateUrl: 'partials/maps.html',
            controller: 'MapsCtrl',
            section: 'maps',
            label: "Mapas"
        }).

        state('maps.region', {
            url: '/:region',
            section: 'maps',
            label: function (params) {
                return params.region;
            }
        }).
}).
```

Comment: Not really, I'm still using the copy/paste solution :(

Comment: In the last version, you can use this option: `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);` You still have to add it in all modules, but it's just one line ;)